# View in HTML instead of console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, rss

I want to show the result of the statement in my HTML page instead of console.log

i am new into this:)

This is the JS:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'xml/articles.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,

      success: function(data) {

          $(data.builds).each(function(index, value){

        console.log(value.number);
          });
      }
  });
```

And this is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title> JSON RSS parser </title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="feed">

        <ul> </ul>

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/logic.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

I tried with this but it did not work:

```
        $('.feed ul').append(
        $('<li />', {
            text: number
        })
        );
    });
},
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the nodes and appending them.

```
var ul = document.querySelector('div.feed > ul');

$(data.builds).each(function(index, value){

  var li = document.createElement('li');
  var text = document.createTextNode(value.number);
  li.appendChild(text);
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to change the URL to a server link?